# How do I create a table using the Spark Cassandra Connector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I've recently begun using the Spark Cassandra Connector and I've manually created my table and been able to save data. Here's a simplified snippet from the docs:

```
CREATE TABLE test.words (word text PRIMARY KEY, count int);
```

```
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("cat", 30), ("fox", 40)))
collection.saveToCassandra("test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count"))
```

Is there a way to create tables programmatically by inferring the schema from case classes without actually writing the raw queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with `saveAsCassandraTable` and `saveAsCassandraTableEx` as [described in documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#saving-rdds-as-new-tables). The first function will create table automatically, based on your data (be careful that it will take one column as a partition key).  The second function will allow your to customize schema by specifying partition key, clustering columns, etc., like this (code is from documentation):

```
val p1Col = new ColumnDef("col1",PartitionKeyColumn,UUIDType)
val c1Col = new ColumnDef("col2",ClusteringColumn(0),UUIDType)
val c2Col = new ColumnDef("col3",ClusteringColumn(1),DoubleType)
val rCol = new ColumnDef("col4",RegularColumn,IntType)

// Create table definition
val table = TableDef("test","words",Seq(p1Col),Seq(c1Col, c2Col),Seq(rCol))

// Map rdd into custom data structure and create table
val rddOut = rdd.map(s => outData(s._1, s._2(0), s._2(1), s._3))
rddOut.saveAsCassandraTableEx(table, SomeColumns("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"))
```